LMEM - When is it okay to not treat repeated measures as a random effect? And other related questions
Design: I have 3 groups, each subject was tested 3 times (3 trials) per time point, on three different time points.
The Independent variables are: Group (A,B, or C), Trial (1, 2, or 3), and Time (0, 2, 4).
Question 1: My model is singular (boundary (singular) fit message) unless I exclude Time as a random factor. In this situation, can I exclude Time as a random factor? If not, what is the solution?
My original model: lmer (score ~ Group*Time + (1+Time | ID)), get boundary (singular) fit message. Time is a continuous variable.
The correlation between the random effects ID (Intercept) and Time is -1.00, which suggests collinearity between random effects, which I don't understand.
New model: lmer (score ~ Group*Time + (1 | ID)), model does not return a warning and the results are nearly identical. If this is not appropriate, what is the solution? In this case, should I just ignore the singular fit message?
Question 2: I suspect that for all time points, subjects will respond differently (slower) in Trials 1 compared to 2 and 3. That is, Trial is not independent. Assuming I have a large enough dataset, how do I include Trial as a Fixed and Random factor? Do I need a nested model?
Is one of these correct? In layman's terms, how are they different?
lmer (score ~ Group*Time*Trial + (1 + Time + Trial | ID)) or lmer (score ~ Group*Time*Trial + (1 + Time | ID) + (1 | Trial))?
Similar to Question 1, if the model is singular, can I exclude Trial as a random factor?
Question 3: Assuming Trial order affects all groups equally or I don't care about Trials, should I still include it as a random effect because it's a repeated measure? And if so, does that mean I have to include it a fixed factor because (I could be wrong) the rule of thumb is that all random effects should be included as fixed effects? And when would I not include a random effect as fixed effect?
Would this be correct? lmer (score ~ Group*Time + Trial + (1 + Time + Trial | ID))?
When is this okay, if ever? lmer (score ~ Group*Time + (1 + Time + Trial | ID))?

Much of your question is covered in the answers to this question. If you don't have enough observations, you will end up with problems like yours when you try to fit a complex random-effects structure with multiple random slopes or nesting. You have to apply your understanding of the subject matter to decide whether it's important or necessary to try to model the distribution of individual-specific slopes. If not, remove unimportant (based on your subject-matter understanding) random effect terms, keeping the fixed-effect terms you are investigating.* If so, a Bayesian model might help either to give a useful model or to illustrate where the problems arise.
Often, however, you just want to correct for within-individual correlations and don't really need to model the distributions of random intercepts and slopes. With a continuous outcome like yours you can then use generalized least squares, as implemented by the gls() function in the R nlme package. See Chapter 7 of Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies for the principles and how to specify useful within-individual correlation structures.

*Remember that random effects with these functions are modeled as Gaussian distributions around the fixed-effect estimates. You thus shouldn't be specifying a random slope for a predictor that isn't included as a fixed effect.
